# Speaker icon in Notification Area has a tooltip but isn't visible

Tags: windows-10, notification-area

After starting my computer, I noticed that the gap between network connection and language should be speaker icon:

[image]

When I move the mouse over the space the hint shows that this is a speaker icon and clickable. It just doesn't show the icon. How can I fix this?

Comment: This is possibly due to Windows not detecting any sound cards/devices on your PC. Try opening "Device Manager" from start menu and seeing if there are any sound devices detected

Comment: @rahuldottech Yes, I have speakers connected.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator I did. It shows the icon, but I don't why it didn't show it before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log out and back in Windows. If that doesn't fix it, restart the computer.

System Tray icons disappearing, multiplying, or exhibiting other weird behavior has been a problem as long as the System Tray (a.k.a. "Notification Area") has existed in Windows. The reasons are many, but logging out or restarting almost always solves the problem.

Comment: If your using Windows, reboot,reboot,reboot!